# Dynamic function call with or without argument and its storage in a class

Tags: c++, c++11

I use c++11 and it's not possible for me to use QTimer because my program is not graphical.

I don't understand how to store my pointer function with their arguments and call this function in my run method.

Thank you for your help.

timer.h :

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Timer {
private:
    atomic_bool done_ {};
    thread worker_{};
    //time interval
    chrono::milliseconds time;
    void run_();
    Fn** fn; // function called
    Args** args; // Argument of this function
public:
   template <class Fn, class... Args>
    Timer(chrono::milliseconds time, Fn&& fn, Args&&... args);
    ~Timer();
};

#endif // TIMER_H
```

timer.cpp :

```
#include "timer.h"

template <class Fn, class... Args>
Timer::Timer(chrono::milliseconds time,Fn&& fn, Args&&... args){
    this->time = time;
    this->fn = fn;
    this->args = args;
    worker_ = thread(&Timer::run_,this);
}
// Thread method
void Timer::run_(){
    while(!this->done_.load()){
        //call function
        this_thread::sleep_for(time);
    }
}

Timer::~Timer(){
    done_.store(true);
    if(worker_.joinable())
        worker_.join();
    else
       cout << "thread termined" << endl;

}
```

Comment: _it's not possible for me to use QTimer because my program is not graphical_: this is plain wrong.

Comment: Use `std::function<void()>` and let the caller handle binding the arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your return type is known and is invariant you can use `std::bind` and `std::function`. To store callable object along with `args` use `std::bind`. But you need a general structure to store the result of `std::bind` and `std::function` can do that.

Declare a `std::function<void()>` in your class and initialize it:

```
template <class Fn, class... Args>
Timer::Timer(chrono::milliseconds time, Fn&& fn, Args&&... args){
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::result_of_t<Fn(Args...)>, void>, "Return type must be void");

    this->time = time;

    auto callable = std::bind(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    this->func = std::function<void()>(callable);

    worker_ = thread(&Timer::run_,this);
}
```

Read about [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).